# Data in memory is re-used instead of executing a new sql query

Tags: c#, wcf, memory

I have a `WCF` service `FooService`.
My service implements a method `LoginAsync` which takes a `User` object as parameters.

```
public async Task<Token> LoginAsync(User user)
{
    var result = await _userManager.GetModelAsync(user.Uname, user.Pword);
    if (result != null && result.Id > 0)
        return await _tokenManager.GetModelAsync(result);                          
    return null;
}
```

Inside this method  we call `_userManager.GetModelAsync(string, string)` which is implemented as follows:

```
public async Task<User> GetModelAsync(string username, string password)
{
    var result =
        (from m in await _userRepo.GetModelsAsync()
            where m.Uname.Equals(username, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
                && m.Pword.Equals(password, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
        select m).ToList();

    if (result.Any() && result.Count == 1)
    {
        var user = result.First();
        user.Pword = null;
        return user;
    }
    return null;
}
```

To mention it again: this is all server-side code.
I never want my service to send back the `Pword` field, even though it is not clear text. I just don't want that information to be on my client-side code.

This is why I'm setting this property to `NULL` when I found a `User` by comparing username and password.

Here's how `_userRepo.GetModelAsync()` is implemented (don't get confused with `_userManager` and `_userRepo`):

```
public async Task<IList<User>> GetModelsAsync()
{
    return await MediaPlayer.GetModelsAsync<User>(_getQuery);
}

private readonly string _getQuery = "SELECT ID, Uname, DateCreated, Pword FROM dbo.[User] WITH(READUNCOMMITTED)";
```

And here `MediaPlayer.GetModelsAsync<T>(string, params IDbParameter[])`

```
public static async Task<IList<T>> GetModelsAsync<T>(string query, params DbParameter[] parameters)
{
    IList<T> models;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Builder.ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = Db.GetCommand(query, CommandType.Text, parameters))
    {
        await con.OpenAsync();
        command.Connection = con;          
        using (SqlDataReader dr = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
            models = ReadModels<T>(dr);
    }
    return models;
}
```

This code works fine the first time executing it after publishing or restarting this service (the service is consumed by a `WPF` application).
But calling `FooService.LoginAsync(User)` a second time, without publishing or restarting the service again, it will throw a `NullReferenceException` in my `_userManager.GetModelAsync` `LINQ` because `Pword` is `NULL`.

Which is really strange to me, because as you can see there is no logic implemented where my data is explicit stored in memory.
Normally my code should execute a sql query everytime calling this method, but somehow it doesn't. It seems like `WCF` does not get its data from my database, instead re-uses it from memory.

Can somehow explain this behavior to me and what I can do against it?

**Edit 26.09.2018**

To add some more details:

The method `_userManager.GetModelAsync(string, string)` always gets called, same for `_userRepo.GetModelsAsync`. I did some file logging at different points in my server-side code. What I also did, is to take the result of `_userRepo.GetModelsAsync`, iterated through every object in it and logged `Uname` and `Pword`. Only `Pword` was `NULL` (did this logging before doing my `LINQ`).
I also logged the parameters `_userManager.GetModelAsync(user.Uname, user.Pword)` receives. `user.Uname` and `user.Pword` are not `NULL`.

Comment: First, my question is.. Is the password stored as plain text in the database? Are you hashing the password when you store a new user, and comparing it to the hash? I'm not seeing any logic to hash the password you're comparing to.

Comment: I think the issue is on the client side. Do you use the `user` object that you get back for the subsequent call?

Comment: It even doesn't reach `_userRepo.GetModelsAsync` which should call the db - why should the query be executed ?

Comment: @Brandon no, the password is not stored as plain text. The logic for this is on the client-side code because I don't want to send a clear text password over the internet. I want it to be hashed as quick as possible.

Comment: @500 no, in my testing I restarted my service-consuming application, in this case a `WPF` application.

Comment: @500 which means,  that I always pass a "full" `User` object to my service. Please take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just noticed that this question was reposed. My diagnosis is the same:

> What I am thinking right now, is that my service keeps my IList with the cleared Pword in memory and uses it the next time without performing a new sql query.

LINQ to SQL (and EF) reuse the same entity objects keyed on primary key. This is a very important feature.

`Translate` will give you preexisting objects if you use it to query an entity type. You can avoid that by querying with a DTO type (e.g. `class UserDTO { public string UserName; }`).

It is best practice to treat entity objects as a synchronized mirror of the database. Do not make temporary edits to them.

Make sure that your `DataContext` has the right scope. Normally, you want one context per HTTP request. All code inside one request should share one context and no context should ever be shared across requests.

So maybe there are two issues: You modifying entities, and reusing a `DataContext` across requests.

Comment: thanks @usr, this helped and I was able to solve my problem.